# Wrong recent deleted posts score

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-answers, score, recently-deleted

When I look at my recently deleted answers I see a list of answers all having zero score.

[image: deleted-answers]

But some of them have scores.

For instance

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24097171
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24084741
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/24080347

Comment: Yep, and I ran into this many times, was going to post this bug, but you seem to be faster ))